# search and replace a character

Tags: r

I have a string like this

```
x<-c("This is a test (120)")
```

I need to replace the empty space between test and ( so that text will be like this

```
x<-c("This is a test(120)")
```

I tried this

```
s<-gsub("\t\v\(", "", x)
```

not working, any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple approach is to used `fixed = TRUE` as in:

```
gsub(" (", "(", x, fixed = TRUE)
```

or:

```
gsub(" \\(", "\\(", x)
```

Comment: As Justin points out this `gsub("\\s+\\(", "\\(", x)` is more generalizable.

Answer (score 3):

Using a lookahead:

```
gsub("\\s+(?=\\()", "", x, perl=TRUE) 
[1] "This is a test(120)"
```

Answer depends on more specifications you require though. Do you want to remove all spaces in front of opening brackets? Or just one? Or only in front of brackets containing numbers?

Answer (score 2):

You have to "double escape" things in R.  One for R and one for the regex:

```
s <- gsub('\\s\\(', '(', x)
```

That said, depending on your specific use case, you might want this to be more robust:

```
s <- gsub('(.+) \\((.+)\\)', '\\1(\\2)', x)
```

Comment: Hi @Justin, having said that. This worked. Now I am trying to revove the extra space at the beginning of the line with this: s <- s <- gsub('^s+','',s), it does not seem to work.

Comment: the package `stringr` has some great string helper functions in it.  but again, you need to escape stuff!  `s <- gsub('^\\s', '', ' test')`. using `stringr` you would use `str_trim(x)`